# Getting closest lower value from a datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to retrieve the closest lower value from a datagridview based on input from a user.

For example, I have these two rows of data:

```
dgvKeyFactorTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 00000m, 1.000m });
dgvKeyFactorTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 150000m, 1.873m });
dgvKeyFactorTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 155000m, 1.938m });
```

If the user inputs 150000, the program correctly references 1.873 with this statement:

```
 var _factorKeyVariable = this.dgvKeyFactorTable.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
.Where(r=>(decimal)r.Cells[0].Value == decimal.Parse(txtCoverageA.Text))
.Select(r=>(decimal)r.Cells[1].Value)
.FirstOrDefault();

factorKey = _factorKeyVariable;
lblKeyFactor.Text = factorKey.ToString();
```

However, I need to be able to have a user input a number that is between the values in this table - for example, 153500, and have the program set the `factorKey` variable according to a formula.

In order for the formula to succeed, I need to reference the closest highest numbers (155000 & 1.938) which I successfully do here:

```
var _factorKeyHigh = dgvKeyFactorTable.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
.Where(r => (decimal)r.Cells[0].Value >= decimal.Parse(txtCoverageA.Text))
.Select(r => (decimal)r.Cells[1].Value)
.FirstOrDefault();

var _keyFactorCoverageHigh = dgvKeyFactorTable.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
.Where(r => (decimal)r.Cells[0].Value >= decimal.Parse(txtCoverageA.Text))
.Select(r => (decimal)r.Cells[0].Value)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

And, I also need to capture the closest lowest values in the table (150000 & 1.873). This is where I'm having trouble. I'm using this code to attempt to do so:

```
var _factorKeyLow = dgvKeyFactorTable.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
.Where(r => (decimal)r.Cells[0].Value <= decimal.Parse(txtCoverageA.Text))
.Select(r => (decimal)r.Cells[1].Value)
.FirstOrDefault();

var _keyFactorCoverageLow = dgvKeyFactorTable.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
.Where(r => (decimal)r.Cells[0].Value <= decimal.Parse(txtCoverageA.Text))
.Select(r => (decimal)r.Cells[0].Value)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

However, this is always returning the lowest value in the table 0, 1.000. I'm not sure why this isn't working, can anyone provide some insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the highest you can do this. I have simplified the query so its more readable and also faster. because you dont have to find one item twice.

```
var highfactor= dgvKeyFactorTable.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .FirstOrDefault(r => (decimal)r.Cells[0].Value >= decimal.Parse(txtCoverageA.Text));

var _keyFactorCoverageHigh = (decimal)highfactor.Cells[0].Value;
var _factorKeyHigh = (decimal)highfactor.Cells[1].Value;
```

But to get the lowest remember that `00000m, 1.000m` is also lower and its lower than `150000m, 1.873m` so `FirstOrDefault();` will give you this because its the first find. Instead use `LastOrDefault();` to get closest item.

Note that `LastOrDefault` also gives you the first find but it will search from end to beginning.

```
var lowfactor= dgvKeyFactorTable.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .LastOrDefault(r => (decimal)r.Cells[0].Value <= decimal.Parse(txtCoverageA.Text));

var _keyFactorCoverageLow = (decimal)lowfactor.Cells[0].Value;
var _factorKeyLow = (decimal)lowfactor.Cells[1].Value;
```

Comment: This code is throwing a null reference exception at `(decimal)r.Cells[0].Value <= decimal.Parse(txtCoverageA.Text)`. "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." any time I change the txtCoverageA field.

I wasn't running into that issue previously. I'm definitely don't have a null value either.

Comment: try `(decimal?)r?.Cells?[0]?.Value <= decimal.Parse(txtCoverageA.Text)`. there must be null value somewhere. this will eliminate them. any way try to find it. currently i have not enough information to help. but this should do the job @JoeCambareri

Comment: note that this is not good to put all question marks everywhere. just do it for test to see if it actually works or not. remove question marks one by one and try to use the least question marks. (except `(decimal?)`). for example remove it from `r?.` if it worked. then remove another from `Cells?` and so on. until you get null exception. that means you have to keep the question mark that you just removed. @JoeCambareri

Comment: That did it. `.LastOrDefault(r => (decimal?)r.Cells[0].Value <= decimal.Parse(txtCoverageA.Text));` is making it work and my formula is returning the expected value. Thank you!

Comment: glad it helped! happy coding ;) @JoeCambareri

Answer (score 1):

FirstOrDefault returns the first element of the sequence.  You're retrieving the first element from the sequence of table entries less than your input value.

You can use LastOrDefault instead for the less-than case.  This returns the last element of the sequence, and should be what you're looking for as long as the sequence is ordered from least to greatest.